# Sinon/sandbox test says that function was never called

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

I want to write a unit test that checks to see if a function was called, but i'm getting the error:

```
submitDetails
       submitDetails
         sendEmail:
     AssertionError: expected sendEmail to have been called exactly once, but it was called 0 times
```

From what I can see my function `submitDetails.submitDetails` clearly runs the function `sendEmail.sendEmail` but it's saying that it's never called. I've also tried just using 'spy.called' instead of `calledOnce` but I get the same result.

Test file:

```
const submitDetails = require('../src/scripts/submitDetails')
const sendEmail = require('../src/lib/sendEmail')

describe('submitDetails', function () {
  let sandbox = null

  before(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox()
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore()
  })

  describe('submitDetails', () => {
    let mockParams, result

    beforeEach(async () => {
      sandbox.spy(sendEmail, 'sendEmail')
    })

    it('sendEmail', () => {
      expect(sendEmail.sendEmail).to.have.been.calledOnce()
    })
  })
})
```

SubmitDetails.js (file that's being test)

```
const { sendEmail } = require('../lib/sendEmail')
const submitDetails = {}

submitDetails.submitDetails = query => {
  return sendEmail(query)
}

module.exports = submitDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call `submitDetails.submitDetails()` method in your test case. Here is the working example:

`sendEmail.ts`:

```js
module.exports = {
  sendEmail() {}
};
```

`submitDetails.ts`:

```js
const sendEmail = require('./sendEmail');
// @ts-ignore
const submitDetails = {};

// @ts-ignore
submitDetails.submitDetails = query => {
  return sendEmail.sendEmail(query);
};

module.exports = submitDetails;
```

`submitDetails.spec.ts`:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon, { SinonSandbox, SinonSpy } from 'sinon';

const submitDetails = require('./submitDetails');
const sendEmail = require('./sendEmail');

describe('submitDetails', () => {
  let sandbox: SinonSandbox;

  before(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  describe('submitDetails', () => {
    let sendEmailSpy: SinonSpy;

    beforeEach(() => {
      sendEmailSpy = sandbox.spy(sendEmail, 'sendEmail');
    });

    it('sendEmail', () => {
      submitDetails.submitDetails();
      sandbox.assert.calledOnce(sendEmailSpy);
      expect(sendEmailSpy.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
  submitDetails
    submitDetails
      ✓ sendEmail


  1 passing (22ms)
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58058653